# Using Regex to Quickly Add Code to Java Methods in Notepad++

Tags: regex, eclipse, notepad++

I am looking for the regex which will let me use search replace to add 2 lines of code to all java methods in file using Notepad++

**Before:**

> ```
>   public void startProcessing() {
>       ..............
>       ..............
>                }
> ```

**After:**

> public void startProcessing() {
>
> ```
>   logger.info( "Entering into startProcessing" );
>   ..............
>   ..............
>   logger.info( "Exiting startProcessing" );
>            }
> ```

Is this possible, if yes can anyone help me with the code... or guide me on any other possible way to do this.

Comment: That's probably the wrong way to go about debugging...

Comment: Why are you trying to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To start with the "bad news", you won't be able to insert the "Exiting" line unless you have a much-better fingerprint to match against. With your current code-sample, the best you can match against is `}` and, as a wild guess, there are probably a lot of closing-curly-brackets throughout your code.

To insert the "Starting" line is do-able, but the robustness depends on your input.

If you will *always* want to replace the same line as in your sample code (or the same format but different function name), you could do the following in the Find+Replace menu:

Find:

```
public void startProcessing() {
```

Replace:

```
public void startProcessing() {\n\tlogger.info("Entering into startProcessing");
```

Search Mode: `Extended`

If you want to *dynamically* do the replacement with a non-hardcoded function name, you could try the following:

Find:

```
(public void )([a-zA-Z0-9_$]+)(.*)
```

Replace:

```
\1\2\3\n\tlogger.info\("Entering into \2"\);
```

Search Mode: `Regular Expression`

This "dynamic" method will require whatever methods you're searching for the be declared in the same format though, `public void functionName...`. I've used `[a-zA-Z0-9_$]` as the character-set for the function names, but you can adjust this to suit your needs.

**UPDATE** (ignore get/set methods)
To ignore get/set methods, such as `getFieldValueUnits()` or `setFieldValueUnits(int val)`, you can use the following `Find` value (the `Replace` is the same-as-above):

```
(public void )(?!get|set)([a-zA-Z0-9_$]+)(.*)
```

This will match all functions that do not start with `get` or `set` (and are declared as `public void`, as above).

Comment: This is great. Its working. Also in most of the medthods in my files there is no 2nd level { }  . 
So I think you might be able to come up with something. Thanks a lot. Rest I will manage.

Comment: Also I forgot to mention any way to exclude get and set methods like getFieldValueUnits ().

Comment: @DebajyotiDas I don't think I could come up with a working example to match `}` in your code without seeing all of it to be honest, and probably not even then. To ignore `get`/`set` methods, assuming they all begin like `getProperty()`/`setProperty()`, you can use: `(public void )(?!get|set)([a-zA-Z0-9_$]+)(.*)` as the "Find" value (I'll update answer with that as well)

Comment: @DebajyotiDas The expression worked perfectly fine for me. `[^set]` means "match all characters that are not `s`, `e`, and `t`", not "dont match `set`". To "not match a word", you need `(?!set)`. I tested in my own installation of notepad++ and it replaced correctly. I'm running version 6.1.3, you? Also, provide a line to "not match" and I can help a little better.

Comment: Sorry for the mistake. **I updated my Notepad++ and its working fine**. And you are right about [^] usage in your last comment.